# POST body for Google Cloud Build - Webhook Triggers

Tags: webhooks, google-cloud-build

The Google Cloud Build - Webhook Trigger [create trigger documentation](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/automating-builds/create-webhook-triggers#creating_webhook_triggers) shows the proper URL to POST to invoke the build trigger.  However the documentation does not describe the POST body, which seems to be required.  I have successfully triggered the cloud build webhooks using `content-type: application/json` header with a POST body of `{}`, but it would be nice to know:

- What is the POST body supposed to be?
- Are we able to pass substitution variables in the POST body?

The [Google Cloud Build - REST API documentation](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.triggers/webhook) provides some additional hints that a [HttpBody](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.triggers/webhook#HttpBody) payload is accepted, but no additional information past that as for as I can tell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The body is what you want! In fact, in your trigger you customize your substitution variable like this (from the documentation)

```
 --subtitutions=\
         _SUB_ONE='$(body.message.test)', _SUB_TWO='$(body.message.output)'
```

So, your body need to be like that

```
{
  "message": {
    "test": "test value",
    "ourput": "my output"
  }
}
```

The data are automatically extracted from your body content. So you can add more substitutions or change the format of your JSON and thus of your substitutions value.

Comment: can you provide a link to the documentation you are referencing?  Looks like this (https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-builds/use-bash-and-bindings-in-substitutions#payload_bindings) might have been the missing piece of the puzzle for me.

Comment: Arf, no, the doc is bad :( I was in the alpha program for the PubSub trigger. And the example is extracted from the PubSub trigger example (the pubsub message has a message structure). It's only by experience with the service and similar trigger. Your question is good, because the doc is bad. You can perform a feedback on the doc page if you want. I will forward it to the Google Cloud PM (product manager).

Comment: OK thanks!  I have already provided feedback on the Webhook Trigger documentation page.  I have tested your solution and it works great, much appreciated.